# Symfony 2.7 - How to load validator?

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I'm having a hard time loading the validator in symfony based on their example in the documentation.

When I do this:

```
 $validator = $this->get('validator');
 $errors = $validator->validate($teacher);
```

I get this:

```
 Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class
   "DBViewerBundle\Repository\SchoolRepository".
    Did you mean to call e.g. "getSchoolInfo" or "getSchools"?
```

I assumed when I got that error it was because this repository class doesn't have 'extend Controller' or something that may include the validator. Tried it with extend Controller, with no luck. Even tried doing it standalone and still get errors. I'm assuming there is something else I have to enable somewhere?

Standalone way, I followed this document:
http://blog.chrisworfolk.com/2012/06/20/using-the-symfony2-validator-component-outside-the-framework/

I get this:

```
Attempted to load class "ValidatorFactory" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Validator".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I definitely have the use there for the Symfony\Component\Validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document you are using is for an outdated version of Symfony. You need to use the Validation class.  Check out their github page for examples: https://github.com/symfony/Validator

All you need is to use the `Validation::createValidator()` method or `Validation::createValidatorBuilder()` method.

Answer (score 0):

A repository should not contain anything other than a query which is responsible of retrieving some data from somewhere. The validator is only available in a `Controller` or in a `Service` (by passing it as a variable when specifying it as a service in `services.yml`).

Furthermore, you can use `Annotations` to make specific requirements for your fields. You can, for example, require a field not to be empty and the string to be withing specific length:

```
// User.php (Entity)

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class User {

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min="6", max="12")
     */
    private $username;

}
```

Now, you just need to have annotation validation enabled (which is usually set to true by default) in `config.yml`:

```
framework:
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
```

In your controller you would only have to do

```
public function yourActionName(Request $request) {
    $form = $this->createForm(....);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()) {
        // perform the action you want when the form is valid.
    }
}
```

Here's the official [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html).